# Is there a way to read the current displayed message?

Tags: message

Ignoring the `*Messages*` buffer which is used for logging messages, and which can be disabled, is there a way to get the current message displayed using Elisp?

---

Asking because there are times when it's impossible to use `inhibit-message` (because `message` is called from C, so I'd like to backup and restore the current `message`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `current-message` function:

> (current-message)
>
> Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 20.
>
> Return the string currently displayed in the echo area, or nil if none.

Code

```el
(progn
  (message "foo")
  (format "current message is %s" (current-message)))
```

will return `"current message is foo"`